# Is a von Neumann algebra a closed linear span of pairwise orthogonal projections?

Tags: linear-algebra, von-neumann-algebras, projection, schauder-basis

It's well known that

> a von Neumann algebra is a closed linear span of its projections.

Can we require these projections to be pairwise orthogonal? that is, can we find a set $\mathscr P$ consists of some projections of a von Neumann algebra such that $pq=0\forall p,q\in \mathscr P$ and the von Neumann algebra is closed linear spanned by $\mathscr P$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unless the algebra is commutative, because pairwise orthogonal projections commute, so any members of their linear span commute.